# Is there some prepostion required between "a wall" and "16 inches on center" in a little bit normal written english

Tags: meaning, expressions

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=19)

> today I'm
>   going to show you how to frame a wall 16
>   inches on center ...

I am awar of what he said, which is a clear expression in everyday speech.

The question is, is there some prepostion required between "a wall" and "16 inches on center" in a little bit normal written english, like (my version)

> I'm going to show you how to frame a wall whose layout is 16 inches on center.

Is my version more approriate for written english or unnecessary and wordy

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disagree with the other answer:

> I'm going to show you how to frame a wall 16 inches on center.

Is correct as written.

Here, "16 inches on center" functions as an adverbial phrase modifying the verb "frame." Syntactically, it's describing the manner in which he will frame the wall, not the wall itself.

This sentence works for the same reason

> I'm going to build a wall out of wood.

and

> I'm going to paint a wall blue.

Work despite the fact that "wall out of wood" and "wall blue" don't work on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, certainly in written English, there would be something between "wall" and "16" here. Your proposed rewriting uses "whose," which is most often only used to refer to something pertaining to a person, not a wall. I can imagine people saying it this way, but it's not right. Of course, construction workers are not known for their impeccable English and the author of that video has one of the most distinctive southern accents I have ever heard (and I live in Texas). He probably uses a lot of speech phrases that a majority of English speakers would find odd.

Note also that "X inches on center" is an idiom used only in the construction industry and is not standard English in other contexts.

Consider the following possibilities:

> Today I'm going to show you how to frame a wall that's 16 inches on center

or

> Today I'm going to show you how frame a wall with a 16 inch stud layout